# Disable some id in js

Tags: javascript

I have a website that has smooth scrolling effect with a javascript. But, the problem is, when the menu becomes burger menu in mobile view, the page will scroll everytime I tab/click on the burger icon. Therefore, I'm looking for a solution to make the page not scrolling when clicking the burger with specified `id=#menu`.

Below the code for my menu:

```
$(document).ready( function(e) {
    var $menu = $('#menu'),
      $menulink = $('.menu-link'),
      $menuTrigger = $('.has-sub-menu > a');

    $menulink.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $menulink.toggleClass('active');
        $menu.toggleClass('active');
    });

    $menuTrigger.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass('active').next('ul').toggleClass('active');
    });
    e.preventDefault();

});`
```

And, below the js code for the smooth scrolling on my page.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
    history.replaceState ("", document.title, e.originalEvent.oldURL);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1000, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

Below the HTML of the menu(requested by someone)

```
 <a href="#menu" class="menu-link"><span></span></a>
  <nav class="menu" id="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#rentcopier">Rent a Copier</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#whyus">Why Choose Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#promotion">Promotion</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

I want the smooth scrolling for all the links but to exclude the link with id#menu so the page won't scroll when I click on the burger menu. I don't know how to exclude that.
I'm not good in js coding. Wish to get help from the experts here. Thank you!

Here is the website link for your reference for better understanding about my question.
[www.lnemacs.com/beta](http://www.lnemacs.com/beta)

Comment: Please, could you show us the html structure of your menu?

Comment: I have added it. Please view it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a `click` event handler to all links (`<a>` elements) in the page, including the menu button. You should just add it to the menu links, like:

```
$(".menu a").on('click', function(event) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: So, I can just add your code to my existing code and it will exclude the scrolling for the #menu?

Comment: No, it's not to be added. Instead of your `$("a").on("click")`, you need to have `$(".menu a").on("click")`

Comment: Oh...i see. I'm sorry! I didn't get it at first. I'm not good in JS code. Now, I have changed it and it works now. Thanks for your solution, Aioros! It's great. :)